# following siblings in xpath returns empty result

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I have this html node

```
<li>
    <em>Description
    </em>
    <br>
    TEXT TEXT                
</li>
```

I want to extract the `Text Text`

I tried this:

```
 sel.xpath('//em[normalize-space(.) = "Description"]/following-sibling::*')
```

I got empty result.

Why please?

#### please I need to check for description, so i hope your answers don't include chaning the checking with description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself and it is

```
'//li[contains(em,"Description")]/text()[last()]'
```

Comment: Was about to suggest that. Glad to see your XPath skills improve Marco :)

Comment: @pault. I always appreciate your efforts and help to me and your support. thank you a lot

Comment: @pault. hello my friend, would you help me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628891/scrapy-spider-returns-value-to-another-spider

Comment: @paultrmbrth he my old friend, could you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353650/scrapy-how-to-import-the-settings-to-override-it i need help

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid XML. Where does the `<br>` close? If it's `<br/>` then it will be empty because the following sibling is the `<br/>`.

Comment: this is the html that i got from the webpage. i can't change it and even if i could, i don't want. i want to extract the data from the website, note fixing their html :)

Comment: If the HTML is not well-formed XML it won't parse and you won't be able to use XPath. You'll have to use something else. Are you sure it's not a <br/> instead of <br>?

Comment: If it is not well-formed, and if you can't fix it, you can try to convert HTML into well-formed XHTML using [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) first. After that you can use XPath.

Comment: yes it is <br> and you should know that every problem has a solution, so please don't tell that `it won't parse` because it will be parsed :P

Comment: lets wait for an answer that doesn't use `xhtml`. i have a lot of pages and my system will have performance problem if i covered my html for every item.

Comment: Well, supposing something there closes the <br> for you to make it work with XPath, then you have to select the node after it: `//em[normalize-space(.) = "Description"]/following-sibling::node()[3]` since `node[2]` is the `<br/>`

Comment: I found the solution and I wrote it in an answer