# scrapy run spider from script

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to run my spider from a script rather than a `scrap crawl`

I found this page

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

but actually it doesn't say where to put that script.

any help please?

Comment: Presumably, you put that code in the script you want to use to run the spider.

Comment: @Talvalin I am asking where should I put the script?

Comment: Providing your system path and PYTHONPATH are set up correctly, you should be able to put the script anywhere you like

Comment: @Talvalin so even my scrapy project should be in pythonpath? if yes. lets say that i have 5 projects to scrap this domain `xxx.com` which one will be fire if all the spiders have the same name but in different projects? i actually have this case

Comment: You don't need to create a project for a simple spider, you can use the command `scrapy runspider`. My answer contains a complete example.

Comment: Cross-referencing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/771848) - should give you a detailed overview on how to run Scrapy from a script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Scrapy from within a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437402/how-to-run-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script)

Answer (score 42):

It is simple and straightforward :)

Just check the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script). I would make there a little change so you could control the spider to run only when you do `python myscript.py` and not every time you just import from it. Just add an `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Now save the file as `myscript.py` and run 'python myscript.py`.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'm done with your code. So, how to save the output to JSON file? If we run scrapy from command prompt or terminal, we can set **scrapy crawl MySpider -o output.json** and we get the output JSON file. If we use your code, where can I put the code to save the output to JSON file? @AlmogCohen

Comment: @syaifulhusein Yup, it is more complicated. I can see that in one of my projects I did the following thing: I've created a Scrapy Pipleline that store processed items in memory. Then at the end of the spider run I took them out of the memory store and manipulate the items as I wish. If willing to open a new question I can answer there with a code example.

Comment: +Almog Cohen I think your code example is the solution to my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141729/get-scrapy-result-inside-a-django-view
Could you answer there, please?

Comment: @PaulozOiOzuLLuFabrício you got it man. See my answer there.
syaifulhusein you can go there as well if you still need an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141729/get-scrapy-result-inside-a-django-view

Comment: Very elegant solution

Comment: @syaifulhusein You can add the location of output by specifying custom settings for a spider, `settings = {"FEED_FORMAT": "json",
"FEED_URI": "/tmp/verizon.json"}                                                        
crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)`

Answer (score 6):

luckily scrapy source is open, so you can follow the way [crawl command](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py) works and do the same in your code:

```
...
crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
crawler.crawl(spider)
self.crawler_process.start()
```

Comment: what is `**opts.spargs` ?

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just do this?

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl myspider".split())
```

Put that script in the same path where you put `scrapy.cfg`

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a normal Python script, and then use Scrapy's command line option [`runspider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-runspider), that allows you to run a spider without having to create a project.

For example, you can create a single file `stackoverflow_spider.py` with something like this:

```
import scrapy

class QuestionItem(scrapy.item.Item):
    idx = scrapy.item.Field()
    title = scrapy.item.Field()

class StackoverflowSpider(scrapy.spider.Spider):
    name = 'SO'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com']
    def parse(self, response):
        sel = scrapy.selector.Selector(response)
        questions = sel.css('#question-mini-list .question-summary')
        for i, elem in enumerate(questions):
            l = scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader(QuestionItem(), elem)
            l.add_value('idx', i)
            l.add_xpath('title', ".//h3/a/text()")
            yield l.load_item()
```

Then, provided you have scrapy properly installed, you can run it using:

```
scrapy runspider stackoverflow_spider.py -t json -o questions-items.json
```

Comment: I get this error on the line `l = scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader(QuestionItem(), elem)` : `exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loader'` . Any idea on how to solve that ?

Comment: @Basj you need to ``import scrapy.contrib.loader`` for that to work.

Comment: Thanks @elias. What should I add to your code here to be able to run it from `python stackoverflow_spider.py` instead of `scrapy runspider ...` ?  I'm really stuck with this little question.

Comment: @Basj Due to the way Scrapy works on top of Twisted, that is not the recommended way to use it: usually you run spiders using scrapy command or deploy the project on an instance of [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org). If you really want to run in a script, I can't add much you'd get from those docs -- I've never done it personally.